# Is a position as embedded software tester a good first step for getting a position as embedded software developer?

Tags: career-development, careers, software

I'm a computer science major with several years of experience developing software with C and C++, and I want to become an embedded software engineer.

I have a job opportunity for being a software verification engineer for an aircraft's control unit software. (I don't know what is exactly that device, but I do know that is embedded software).

Do you think that this is a good first step to get into embedded software development? (Or, in other words, is it easy to move from test / verification to development)

PD.: Taking into account that I have a very low skills in hardware.

Comment: I think this is quite opinion-based, you may get many points of view. However, seems to me that you are already in the industry (embedded software), so a horizontal move to another position doesn't sound impossible to me.

Comment: Actually I am not in that industry, but I would really want to be in it.

Comment: Well, I meant that if you land that job you *will* be in the industry, where many things are possible

Comment: It could, but I wouldn't do it for very long. Some people think you're either a tester or a developer. If you want to develop, you have to build things to prove you can.

Comment: "Should I do X or Y to advance my career" questions are off topic. We don't know you, we don't know your company, and we can't predict the future. See https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695 for details.

Comment: I have not asked what I should do, I have asked what's is the chance for moving from embedded software validation to development. (with other words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, I think this is potentially a good move on your part.  Many of my colleagues have worked their way up from being on the helpdesk, to a QA position, and then finally into the ranks of software engineering.

There are of course many variables to this, including *the companies culture and your hard work*, but yes in general a good beginning move it could be.

YMMV